# optional parameter along with required parameter in flask app routes

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm trying to put an optional parameter alongside a required parameter in one route in Flask app. but it doesn't work.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/route1/', defaults = {'optional_para': "None"}) # or keyword None
@app.route('/route1/<string:optional_para>/<string:required_para>')
def myfunction(optional_para, required_para):
   if optional_para == "something":
       # return this
   else:
       # return this

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

it gives me some jsondecode error and 404 on server.
I figured that if I do the same thing with only one of either required or Optional parameter..then the code works fine.
My work requires me to use them both together.. Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you try the required_parameter first and then the optional one?

Comment: I tried it once before posting this question.. it didn't work..but somehow now it worked.. what just happened here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it will be easy if you consider othr parameters by using `request.args.get` as in the following example

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/route1/<required_para>')
def myfunction(required_para):

   optional_para=request.args.get('optional_para', 'somthing_else', type=str)

   if optional_para == "something":
       # return this
   else:
       # return this

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

and you can invoke the function in return from other view function

```
return redirect(url_for('myfunction',required_para='anything',optional_para='something'))
```

or through html:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('myfunction',required_para='anything',optional_para='something')}}">
click me
</a>
```

or directly in url as

```
http://hostname:prot/route1/'anything?optional_para='something'
```